# How to enable stop recording button in BigBlueButton?

Tags: bigbluebutton

How to stop recording in BigBlueButton. I can only see the Pause recording button. Have checked the bigbluebutton.properties file and couldn't find any relevant stuff on that too. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. BBB always records, if recording is globally enabled and activated in the room settings.
The record/pause button simply marks the timestamps so that BBB can cut the recording during post-processing when the conference is finished.